# vertical align of data in a gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I want my data to be displayed vertically instead of horizontal inside a gridview because there are about 65 fields and it is not coming in size for printing.

The actual view like this:

[image]

But I want in the form :

[image]

Can anybody help me...

Comment: Why cant you change `orientation` to `horizontal` when printing?

Answer (score 1):

You can put the grid in some div and set the rotation of that div to 90 degree with css.

```
.vertial-orientation
{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);   
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

<div class="vertial-orientation">

    <!-- put your grid here -->

</div>
```

Note the support of tranform is required by the browser to apply the css.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this property

```
GridView1.RowStyle.VerticalAlign
```

Example:

```
GridView1.RowStyle.VerticalAlign=VerticalAlign.Top
```

Also try,

```
<ItemStyle VerticalAlign="Top"></ItemStyle>
```